# Hibernate - One to Many Mapping of Set - Annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Newbie to Hibernate here. I'm building a simple app to play around with Hibernate and I'm getting the hang of most of the annotations but the mappings are really confusing me.

I have a `Person` class and I have a `Note`'s class. A person can have many notes associated with them but a single note will only ever correspond to a specific person.

I'm trying to set it up so that the `note` table has a column called `person_id` such that I won't need an extra `person_note` table in the database for the associations.

How would I go about setting up the annotations such that an extra table is not created in the database and I can associate multiple notes to a single person via an extra column in the `note`'s table?

I've tried a few options after searching on Google such as using annotations like this but with no luck:

```
@JoinColumn(name="id_person", nullable=false)
```

**Person Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @OneToMany()
    private Set<Note> notes;

    public Set<Note> getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(Set<Note> notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    ...

}
```

**Note Class**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "note")
public class Note {

    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

   ...

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

---

## Final Working Solution

For the benefit of anyone looking in the future, I now don't have a separate table for mapping `note` objects to `people` objects. The final code (with extra lines removed) now looks like this:

**Person Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Note> notes;

    ...

}
```

**Note Class**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "note")
public class Note {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_person", nullable = false)
    private Person person;

   ...

}
```

**Misc Points**

- I had to add `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` in the `Person` class to ensure that when I saved a `Person` object that all the `Note` objects inside were saved.
- I combined the code from [chsdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496074/hibernate-one-to-many-mapping-of-set-annotations/29496456#29496456) and [Saif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496074/hibernate-one-to-many-mapping-of-set-annotations/29496237#29496237). Thank you to both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your mapping annotations you should map the entities with a `mappedBy` property in the `@OneToMany` annotation and specify a *joinColumn* under the `@ManyToOne` annotation using the `@JoinColumn` annotation, Change your code like this:

**Person class:**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person") // "person" here refers to the person property in the notes class
private Set<Note> notes;
```

**Notes class:**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_person", nullable = false)
private Person person;
```

Take a look at [**Hibernate Collection mapping**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html) for further information.

Comment: This was the first answer and it helped sort out the mapping. I had to tweak it a bit to save the notes objects as well when saving the person but apart from that this worked. I will update the answer to reflect the final working version. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Edit `Person`

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER , mappedBy = "person")
private Set<Note> notes;
```

And `Note`

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false)
private Person person;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you. One can implement what you're asking with only the two tables you already have.

Here is what I would do:

***Database wise:***

Table Person, with:
 PK column: person_id

Table Note, with:

1. PK column: note_id
2. column: person_id  (nullable)
3. column: assigned_person_id (nullable with unique index)

Purpose:

1. **person_id** - reference to the PK of the Person table. That will define the [Person : Note] relationship, where 1 person can have multiple notes.
2. **assigned_person_id** - reference to the person assigned to the note. However to guarantee your requirement that only one person can be assigned to a note - add an unique index by that column. That will guarantee that the same person_id was on used for another note record.

***Hibernate wise:***

**Note** that the code snippet is not complete! It is just pointing the important moments.
You can look at one of the many complete examples, for instance:
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

```
public class Person {

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
   public setNotes(Set<Note> notes) { 
     this.notes=notes;
   }

...          
}

@Table(name = "note", catalog = "schema_name", 
uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "assigned_person_id"))    
public class Note {    
  private Person person;
  private Person assignedPerson;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false)
  public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
  }

  public Person getAssignedPerson() {
    return assignedPerson;
  }

  ...

}
```